# Count how many students if their average score is known

Tags: statistics

If score is integer 1-100.

```
score -> student(s)
60 -> 1 student [60]
50.5 -> 2 students with total score 101
50.5 -> 10 students with total score 505 -> false, because minimum is 2 students.
32.5 -> 2 students [60, 5]
32.5 -> 10 students with total score 325 -> false, because minimum is 2 students.
```

How to find the minimum students?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Why can't the second one be `50.5 -> 2 students with total score 101`?

Comment: @gowrath, Yes, you are right. I just can't count the minimum. edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call $n$ the minimum number of students and $s$ the score. I think $n$ is just:  $n = min\{ k \ \vert \ sk \in \mathbb N\}$ for some integer $k$. That is, if you write $s$ in its reduced rational number form $s = \frac{p}{q} $ for coprime integers $p$ and $q$, then $n = q$ (this question is not valid for the irrationals).

Examples:
$$
\begin{split}
s=60 = \frac{60}{1} \qquad ------> \qquad \text{students} = 1 \\
s=50.5 = \frac{505}{10} = \frac{101}{2} \qquad  ------> \qquad \text{students} = 2 \\
s=32.5 = \frac{325}{10} = \frac{65}{2} \qquad ------> \qquad \text{students} = 2 \\
s=32.222\ldots = \frac{290}{9} \qquad------> \qquad \text{students} = 9 \\
\end{split}
$$

Feel free to correct me on this.